# Binding to the UserControl Inside HierarchicalDataTemplate in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding, datatemplate

I have customized TreeView in usercontrol.
In the HierarchicalDataTemplate I have an image with direction (arrow for the example).

When the application\UserControl flow direction change I need to flip the image.

So i tried binding the Image.FlowDirection (Which is flipping the image automatic when RightToLeft) to the UserControl.FlowDirection

```
<Image FlowDirection="{Binding Path=FlowDirection, 
                               ElementName=MyUserControl}" ... />
```

But it is not working. I guess because he can't find the UserControl from inside the template.
I've tried this binding outside the template - and it's working fine.

Any solution ?
How can I get my UserControl from inside the template ?

--UPDATE--

There are two places of binding in this xaml. The first is in the style of the button, and it is working, and the second in the template of the TreeViewItem - and there it's not working.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyTree"
...
    d:DesignHeight="218" d:DesignWidth="284" x:Name="MyLayerListControl">
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                ...
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <Border x:Name="CloseButtonBorder" BorderThickness="0" Margin="3" CornerRadius="0" Background="Gray" >

<!-- THIS BINDING IS WORKING -->
                                <Image Source="{StaticResource back}" Margin="2"
 FlowDirection="{Binding Path=FlowDirection, ElementName=MyLayerListControl}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

<Button Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}" />    

<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>


     <Grid.Resources>
         <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="LayerListTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Childrens}" >
             <Grid>
               <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFBADDE9" Opacity="0.5"  /> 
               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                  <!-- The Item -->
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">

<!-- THIS BINDING IS NOT WORKING -->
                     <Image x:Name="ArrowImage" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{StaticResource arrow}" 
FlowDirection="{Binding Path=FlowDirection, ElementName=MyLayerListControl}"/>

                  </StackPanel>

               </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LayerListTemplate}" x:Name="MyTreeView" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Try '{Binding Path=DataContext.FlowDirection, ElementName=MyUserControl}

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working

Comment: Can you post the complete code of what is not working?

Comment: Make sure the x:Name=MyUserControl is set in the xaml as well.

Comment: The name is for sure set well because i'm using the same binding somewhere else in the xaml and it is working. I'm posting simplify xaml in a sec

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris says, add "DataContext" in front of you binding path, as you are binding to the Control itself, so if FlowDirection is a property of the DataContext, you need to have that.

Also, make sure you have Mode=TwoWay in your binding.

As an alternative, you can you use RelativeSource so you don't have to hard code an ElementName.

Check out: http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/12/7th-day-of-silverlight-ancestor-relative-source-binding/

Comment: The problem is that i'm using silverlight 4 - 3rd party restriction. and there is no AncestorType in version 4.